# Thrown an error when I try to convert String to Integer

Tags: java

I have tried to parse a string to integer in my code, but its throw me an error.
See below is my code:

```
String phy=(String)map.get("hw.physmem");
int mem_phys=Integer.parseInt(phy);
String page=(String)map.get("hw.pagesize");
int pagesize=Integer.parseInt(page);
System.out.println("*******************************************");
System.out.println("Physmem ::: "+mem_phys);
System.out.println("Pagesize ::: "+pagesize);
```

I know the value of the both the String variable

```
map.get("hw.physmem"); returns 1060528128
map.get("hw.pagesize"); returns 4096
```

But, when I try to parse the value of String to int its throw an error like below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1060528128"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:447)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
        at FreeBsd.main(FreeBsd.java:33)
```

I couldn't find the error, Please share your ideas for this problems...

Comment: There's a leading space in your number string..

Comment: Very thoughtful of the JDK developers to include quotes in the error message. Otherwise this would be very hard to spot.

Comment: Where are you populating this map from, since it's including unwanted space, and why aren't you using generics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see from the error message that the String you tried to parse had a leading white space - `" 1060528128"`.

Try to trim the white spaces before parsing :

```
int mem_phys=Integer.parseInt(phy.trim());
int pagesize=Integer.parseInt(page.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trim any leading zero before converting:
So as your exception states `1060528128` should be `1060528128`.

Answer (score 0):

[String.trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())

```
int mem_phys=Integer.parseInt(phy.trim());
int pagesize=Integer.parseInt(page.trim());
```

instead of

```
int mem_phys=Integer.parseInt(phy);
int pagesize=Integer.parseInt(page);
```